# Is JAX-RS compiled for JAVA 1.5 ..I am trying for a REST Client here..If so what would be the version which is compatible for the same?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-rs

I am currently working on migration work from SOAP to Rest consumption. I want to know

1. what is the best api for rest client (in my case there is no spring and Java version is 1.5)
2. Does JAX-RS or Apache CXF supports Java 1.5 if so what would be the version of those for dependency??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rest clients for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java)

Comment: Are you really sure that you want to work with Java 1.5? It is quite old.

Comment: This link would help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27326421/1401019

Answer (score -1):

1. If you haven't worked so far with any REST-API, I would suggest to start with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [JAX-RS](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html). They are pretty much de facto standard.
2. JAX-RS was introduced in Java EE 6. ([Java API for RESTful Web Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services)). Hence, JAX-RS is not part of Java 1.5. About Apache CXF, it is compatible with Java 1.5. [CanCXFrunwithJDK1.5](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-CanCXFrunwithJDK1.5?)

Comment: So what would be the best one for me (java 1.5) does cxf supports here?

Comment: I have completed my answer.